Getting the mobile push subscription for each subscriberkey
We have a data extension with a subscriber key column. We need to ensure this column is populated using either the device ID or contact ID. Additionally, we want to determine if contacts are subscribed for mobile push notifications.
To achieve this, I've been asked to populate the subscriber key field for all contacts, regardless of their opt-in or opt-out status or whether they've received mobile push notifications.
I'm wondering if there's an available API (REST or SOAP) that can provide us with mobile push information, including device ID, opt-in status, platform, and other relevant details?
For instance, we have this API for SMS
Regards.

You start by saying you have a list of subscriber keys and then mention there's a DE where you need to populate the "subscriber key" field. Can you clarify what you have and don't have at the moment? What's the DE you are mentioning?

you're right, my bad. Just updated the question. Thanks for pointing that out.
